# Is there a place to get more granular reporting data via API?

Tags: reporting, google-admin-sdk, phishing

I'm trying to figure out a way to export some of the events I can see in the security dashboard and alert center. The Customer Reports API only gives me the # of mail received per day, and # or spam messages per day, but is more than 24 hrs behind.

I've tried to create an alert in the security alerts center for whenever my domain gets a relevant email, but I just get an email once a minute that says the the threshold was exceeded, and I have to click into the investigation tool to actually get the relevant data.

Is there a place I can request # of phishing emails per hour, or be alerted whenever new phishing emails are found. Or Malware, etc.

Comment: When you say `# of phishing emails per hour` - do you mean emails that Gmail automatically classified as Spam?

Comment: no, within the Security Dashboard, it breaksdown the spam into categories. Malware, Phishing, etc. It also tells you why the emails were detected as spam, ie: content, blacklist, custom security rules, ML, DMARC or SPF records, etc. There is a wealth of information in there, that I'm trying to get out so I can do some additional analysis, but right now, it seems like the only # you can get is # of SPAM per hour, and even that is about 2 days delayed.

Answer (score 0):

- The Reports API method [UserUsageReport: get](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/userUsageReport/get) allows you to retrieve received spam emails for a certain date by specifying the parameter `gmail:num_spam_emails_received`
- However, if you want to retrieve e.g. the emails from the last hour, there is no prebuilt functionality for this.

### You can write a [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) that would browse your Gmail Inbox for new Spam Emails and set the script on a [time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers)

Sample:

```
function setmeOnHourlyTimer() {
  var now = new Date();
  var oneHourAgoinSeconds = Math.round(now.getTime()/1000 - 1200 *60);
  var query = '"after:'+ oneHourAgoinSeconds  +'"';
  var spamMessages = Gmail.Users.Messages.list("YOU_EMAIL", {"labelIds": ["SPAM"] , "q": query}).messages;
  if (spamMessages.length > 0){
    GmailApp.sendEmail("paste your email here", "You have new Spam emails", "You got " + spamMessages.length + " new spam message(s) within the last hour.")
  }
}
```

Comment: this is for an individual user, I'm looking for the information for an entire organization.

Comment: You can do it for the whole domain if you set-up a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-accounts). Unfortunately, there is no possibility to do it for the recent emails on hourly basis with the Reports API, so you need to implement a workaround.

Comment: even with this workaround, you still only get "spam/inbox" stats. The security dashboard gives you additional details about why it was detected as spam, and if the spam classification is Phishing / Malware, etc. So this will work to get more recent spam data, but won't solve the granularity issue. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately right now there is no better way to do it. If the workaround I proposed is not good enough for your needs, all I can do is recommend you to file a feature request  on [Google's Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) and hope that it will be implemented in the future.